# Are these roots the only ones or are there more roots?

Tags: analysis

I am looking at the following exercise:

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ integrable. Show that $\exists  \xi \in [a,b]$ such that $\int_a^{\xi} f(u) du= \int_{\xi}^{b} f(u) du$

We define $G(x)=\int_a^{x} f(u) du+  \int_{b}^{x} f(u) du$

$$\int_a^{x} f(u) du \text{ and } \int_{b}^{x} f(u) du \text{ are uniformly continuous at} [a,b],\text{ so } G \text{ is also uniformly continuous }$$

- $G(a)=- \int_a^b f(u) du$
- $G(b)=\int_a^b f(u) du$

So, $G(a) \cdot G(b) \leq 0$

- $G(a) \cdot G(b) <0$:
  $$G \text{ is uniformly continuous at } [a,b],\text{ so it is also continuous at this interval, so from the Bolzano theorem } \exists \xi \in (a,b) \text{ such that } \int_a^{\xi} f(u)du= \int_{\xi}^b f(u)du$$
- At the case $G(a) \cdot G(b)=0$, are the only possible roots $\xi=a \text{ and } \xi=b$,are there also other ones?

Comment: the solution is much easier. Let $G(x)=\int_a^{x} f(u) du$. How can you use it to find the needed $x$?

Comment: I don't know right now...could you give me a hint?

Comment: you need $G(x) = G(b)/2$

Comment: If $\int_a^b f(u)\,du = 0$ (that is $G(a)\cdot G(b) = 0$), there _may_ be zeros of $G$ in the open interval $(a,b)$, but there need not be any.

Comment: A ok... Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be more roots. Take for example $f(x)=\sin x$, $x\in[0,4\pi]$.

Then,
$$\int_0^{x}\sin udu=1-\cos x$$
and
$$\int_x^{4\pi}\sin udu=\cos x-1$$

The equation
$$1-\cos x=\cos x-1$$
has three solutions in the intrerval, namely $0$,$2\pi$ and $4\pi$.

To guarantee uniqueness you need $f$ to be monotonic. (Maybe with slightly weaker conditions, such monotonic almost always it can also be guaranteed).

Comment: So... in this exercise I just have to use that there is at least one $x$ for which $G(x)=0$ ?

Comment: Yes. Proofs of existence are just that: of existence. If they asked for uniqueness' proof, they would say it explicitly.

Comment: I understand...thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

It may be more fruitful to define $$H(x) = \int_a^x f(u) \, du - \int_x^b f(u) \, du.$$ If $H(a) = 0$ you are done. Otherwise note that $H(a) = - H(b)$ so that one of these numbers is positive and the other is negative. There exists $\xi$ with $H(\xi) = 0$ because $H$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Comment: So the only points at which $H(x)=0$ are $a \text{ and } b$ ?

Comment: Note that $H$ is the same as $G$.

Comment: I know...So,$H(x)=0$ only at the cases $x=a$ and $x=b$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to "are there no other roots?" is not necessarily.  For example, set $f(x)=0$, then every value of $x$ is a root, i.e. $H(x)=0$ for all $x$ (as defined in @Umberto's solution).